# Can i get pop-up notifications on my Moto E4?

Tags: motorola-moto-e, toast-notifications

I just got my new Moto E4, it's my first Android too, so i'm still figuring everything out and i don't know if i just haven't found the settings or it doesn't do what i want. My old Nokia Lumia would put a little pop-up banner notification at the top of my screen (even when my phone was locked, the screen would light up) whenever i got a notification. However, my E4 only chimes, whether the phone is unlocked and the screen is on or not.

It shows an icon on the screensaver when i move my phone, which i can touch to see a message preview, and the lockscreen does show a constant notification after a message is received. But i want to know if there's any way to get a banner at the top of my screen (locked or otherwise) as the notification happens, without having to touch my phone to see what the notification was. Are there any settings for this? Or an app maybe?
Thanks.

Ps. I found an option for it in Whatsapp but nowhere else (although i haven't seen it in action yet so idk what it's like)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no option on the Moto E4 in settings to enable these types of pop-up notifications, so you will have to either go into each app (like you did with WhatsApp) and enable pop-up notifications or install an app from the Google Play Store.

An app that I use on my phone is called Heads Up Notifications - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=codes.simen.l50notifications&hl=en

Comment: Ah, i guess i just have to live with it then, thanks anyway.